# Laravel: How to get the current url as a view helper with parameters

Tags: php, laravel, view-helpers

I want to build a link in my view that refers to the same page like that one where its placed on. And I want to be able to give a parameter with.

For example I want to change languages. I have a route like

```
domain.com/{lang}/xyz
```

And in my view I want to do something like

```
<a href="{{ URL::action(this, ['lang' => 'en']) }}">EN</a>
```

So I can easily reload the page but just change the "lang" parameter.

Hopefully its understandable. Please try to help me.

(Another side question: Are there no ressources eg a list of all view helpers in Laravel? where do i know which viewhelpers are available?)

Answer (score 22):

Use laravel's helper method to use in a view:

```
url()->current()
```

This will get the current `URL`. If you need to get the current route name,

```
Route::current()->getName()
```

Now you can use this route name to create your own new URL.

eg:

```
<a href="{{ URL::action(Route::currentRouteName(), ['lang' => 'en']) }}">EN</a>
```

Your route definition may be something like:

```
Route::get('/{lang}/about/', ['as'=>'about_us', 'uses'=>'PagesController@about'])
```

This will provide you the current URL.

But in your case, it's better to use the this package for multi language: 
https://github.com/mcamara/laravel-localization

It's pretty simple and easy to use.

Comment: Thats not answering my question.

Comment: url()->current() how should i use that inside my <a href="">EN</a> and give the {lang} parameter with it?

Comment: And without using php in my view? Laravel is using a template engine so you dont have to handle php code in your views. Model-View-Controller, remember?
There should be a viewhelper for that.

Comment: Just use `<a href="{{ URL::action(Route::current()->getName(), ['lang' => 'en']) }}">EN</a>`

Comment: Also `<a href="{{ URL::action(Route::currentRouteName(), ['lang' => 'en']) }}">EN</a>`

Comment: gives me: ErrorException in UrlGenerator.php line 590:
Action app\Http\Controllers\ not defined. (View: /var/www/html/app/webapp/resources/views/main.blade.php) (View: /var/www/html/app/webapp/resources/views/main.blade.php)

Comment: Inspect in HTML if you are getting the correct `URL` and try to see if you made the right route and controller methods.